# Make loaded swf flexible in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have a swf made with Flash CS4 (it contains several buttons, labels & a view-image area). If I open it in browser, it's flexible (i.e. auto-stretch & resize). But if I load it into my Flex program using swfloader, it's not.

What can I adjust it's fla file in Flash CS4 to make it flexible in Flex?

p.s. I ask this because I wish to avoid the complex adjust-geometry-of-all-components coding.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't think it is the configuration of the SWFLoader in the Flex program that is the problem?  From what you've said so far, that's what I would surmise.  For example, have you tried changing `scaleContent` and `maintainAspectRatio`?

Comment: I got a reply from adobe forum suugest me set width & height to 100% & this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Answer is in comment of question!